# Nginx: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, vps

I have a `vps` server by `Reg.ru` and `domain` by `freenom`.

On the `Reg.ru` I added `domain` via `dnsadmin`. All right. Notes are created. Status - `synchronized`.

On the `freenom` in the management panel of `domain` are next fields: `Name`, `Type`, `TTL`, `Target`. `Name` - empty, `TTL` - `3600`, `Type` - `A`, `Target` - `ip` of `vps` server. Status - `active`.

## Nginx

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject** and **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location /static/ {
    root /home/myproject;
  }
  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
  }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
...
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;
}
```

`nginx -t` - `successful`

`systemctl status nginx` - `active`

**ufw status**

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When I open ip of `vps-server` in browser I get *home page of `nginx`*.

---

## gunicorn

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/myproject
ExecStart=/home/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
--access-logfile - \
--workers 3 \
--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
myproject.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# cat /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

`systemctl status gunicorn` - `active`

---

## Django

**/home/myproject/myproject/.settings.py**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', 'localhost']

DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': 'test_db',
         'USER': 'test_user',
         'PASSWORD': 'test',
         'HOST': 'localhost',
         'PORT': '',
     }
}
```

I'm run a `manage.py runserver` and get response from `Django`, that the server is started on `127.0.0.1:8000`.

But when I open web-site by `domain` name (f.e., `example.com`), I get error:

> Unable to access site
>
> Failed to find the IP address of the example.com server.

Comment: When you run it with `manage.py runserver`, I think you'd have to go to `example.com:8000`. Does that work? Or better yet, the IP address of the server + `:8000`.

Comment: Thank you. It's worked. How can I disable port (`8000`) in url?

Comment: That's what you need gunicorn for. Turn off the `runserver` instance and try running `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi` But replace `myproject.wsgi` with your actual `wsgi` file. Then try again with `8000` in the URL. If that works, then something in your nginx config is not working.

Comment: @SamCreamer `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi` - working

Comment: Alright, so gunicorn is able to serve your application, and you have configured systemd as well... Try this: `file /run/gunicorn.sock` to make sure that `/run/gunicorn.sock` actually exists

Comment: I got `/run/gunicorn.sock: socket`

Comment: Weird... I can't see anything wrong just by looking at this, maybe another set of eyes would help. There may be a weird typo somewhere... I guess you've restarted `nginx` since making that `sites-enabled` file?

Comment: I maked typo in `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;`

Comment: There you go! Glad it's solved